# Java Static ArrayList<Listener>

Tags: java, static, listener, observer-pattern

Im working on a small java library and I got a Class named Operation which is a task to process, for now all the tasks are running in a singleThreadExecutor (sequentially).

I made my own Listener and everything to be able to monitor the current operation being processes.

Im storing my observers in a CopyOnWriteArrayList inside my Operation class.

My biggest concern is that i will create a lot of Operation object and i am unlikely to register more than 1-2 observers. I really dont like the idea of creating a CopyOnWriteArrayList for each Operation instance.

I thought about making my CopyOnWriteArrayList static and make a static method to let the observers register to all the operation but i dont know it seems to be a bad design idea overall...

Anyone has a better idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really dont like the idea of creating a CopyOnWriteArrayList for
>   each Operation instance

Why not? It's the correct thing to do. If you are worried about memory or performance, then I suggest you look at the source for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` - it's more efficient than you think. It's essentially backed by an array, with its `Iterator` (`COWIterator`) simply indexes into its backing array. `new CopyOnWriteArrayList()` starts off with an empty array, so the memory overhead is the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` itself.